# react rendering text without new line

Tags: reactjs

there is a text console log like this:

[image]

But rendering this text in a div;

```
  const renderContent = () => {
      console.log(`content`, content)
      return <div>{content}</div>
    }
```

looks like this:
[image]

how to ensure this text has also new line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
return (
   <pre>
      {content}
   </pre>
)
```